# nodejs: function template without return value

Tags: node.js, function-templates, node-gyp

I followed the instruction of [node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_factory_of_wrapped_objects) to implement factory wrapped objects.
So far it works. But what I dont get to work is a function without a return value.
I.e.: (extension of the example in the link)
In `myObject.h`:

```
tpl->PrototypeTemplate()->Set(String::NewSymbol("some"),
  FunctionTemplate::New(something)->GetFunction());

static void something (const v8::Arguments& args);
```

and in `myObject.cc`

```
void MyObject::something(const Arguments& args) {
  .. something without return value ...
}
```

does not work. Why?

I get the following errors:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(const v8::Arguments&)’ to ‘v8::InvocationCallback {aka v8::Handle<v8::Value> (*)(const v8::Arguments&)}’ [-fpermissive]
error: initializing argument 1 of ‘static v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::InvocationCallback, v8::Handle<v8::Value>,  v8::Handle<v8::Signature>)’ [-fpermissive]
```

do i really need a return value? i mean i coud return null and ignore it, not a problem but thats not really a nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because [`FunctionTemplate::New()`](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1FunctionTemplate.html#af9012aee4a102c4018fec8e9532cb996) expects an [`InvocationCallback`](http://izs.me/v8-docs/namespacev8.html#a2084c6d4a8bbd7cb65af83251aa59d04), which has a `return` type of `Handle<Value>`.

So, you'll have to `return` something, but it can simply be `Undefined()`:

```
Handle<Value> MyObject::something(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    return scope.Close(Undefined());
}
```

This makes it equivalent to:

```
function something() {}
```

Which has an implicit `return;` (or `return undefined;`).